# Enviar email automáticamente después de 8 horas php

Tags: php, phpmailer, yii

He creado un email con phpmailer. Y funciona asi:
-insertan datos al formulario y guarda fecha de ingreso
-después de pasar 8 horas, debe validar el tiempo y enviar el correo.

Intenté con task scheduler, que cada 5 minutos abra el enlace y se envie. Funciona pero con el tiempo será molesto que me abra muchas link.

También probé con un batch file, pero como es un enlace siempre abre nueva pestaña en el navegador.

Alguna sugerencia para cambiar esto?

Estoy utilizando php, phpmailer y yii, gracias

Comment: Una tarea cron.

Comment: En windows? Yo investigué de eso pero leí que no era posible hacerlo en Windows

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron

Comment: Ya probé con el programador de tareas, pero siempre abre el enlace. O habrá una forma diferente para evitar que me habrá nueva pestaña en el navegador?

Comment: @LissetteRomero, en la tarea programada no pongas un enlace (URL) a tu proyecto, sino un comando del tipo `/ruta/php /ruta/script.php`

Comment: @Triby acabo de intentar asi, cambie mi codigo, decidi intentar con un archivo .bat, pero muestra el error **Fatal error: uncaught error: class php mailer** 
Como puedo evitar ese error?

Comment: @LissetteRomero, en el archivo BAT incluye el comando para cambiar a la carpeta donde está el script.